# In C, can unused labels always be removed and keep a program working?

Tags: c, label

If a C source has an unused label, the only reason I can think it might be (currently) useful is if somebody was using it as a "bookmark" to easily find a section of code. Barring such reasons, is there any technical reason why unused labels might not want to be removed? In other words, is it possible to break a compilation unit by removing them so such that external compilation units may somehow use it?

EDIT: The specific code I am modifying is pre-C89 so historical C behaviour may make a difference.

Comment: label as in labeled statements the ones used with goto?

Comment: If they're really unused, it should be safe to remove them.  For it to break something there'd have to be something mysterious and wrong about the code or compiler, I think.

Comment: if its only used for bookmarking I guess it won't break anything However I don't have the C documentation with me right now so its better to wait for an asnwer.

Comment: You could also try measuring the impact by asking the compiler to generate assembly output and compare builds with and without the labels.

Comment: Your code uses asm statements? A label in a C module is generally emitted by the compiler as a standard assembler label. So while what I put in my answer remains correct for C statements under language control, an embedded assembler statement can use labels to jump between functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is surely safe for **C99**, **C11** standards where is clearly stated that:

> **A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope**.
>   It can be used (in a goto statement) anywhere in the function in which
>   it appears, and is declared implicitly by its syntactic appearance
>   (followed by a : and a statement).

So if the label is unused inside the function you can remove it.

**PS** In **C89** standard we have:

> **A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope**.
>   It can be used (in a goto statement) anywhere in the function in which
>   it appears, and is declared implicitly by its syntactic appearance
>   (followed by a : and a statement).  **Label names shall be unique within
>   a function**.

Once again labels are confined in function scope, but also in the old glorious book **K&R C-language**, page 58 **§3.8 Goto and labels**, says:

> A label has the same form as a variable name, and is followed by a
>   colon. It can be attached to any statement in the same function as the
>   goto. **The scope of a label is the entire function**.

So you can remove them from everywhere safely enough.

Comment: The code base I am upgrading is pre-C89. I will mention this in the question. Your answer is very helpful however and may eventually get the green checkmark.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII You're welcome. Please see my update.

Comment: You're awesome. Buying a copy of the K&R book has been on my todo list for many years. I really need to do that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII The K&R book is a World Heritage and should be adopted by UNESCO indeed. But you can find a copy on the net, just search for "K&R C language pdf" ;-)

Comment: the fastest way to determine if a label can be removed is to comment it and re-compile.